# Altera Quartus falsly says Modelsim isn't installed

Tags: modelsim, intel-fpga, quartus

Installed Quartus 13.0 with Modelsim in Fedora 22 64-bit. Running Quartus in 32-bit because I get lots and lots of problems otherwise. However, I can start Quartus, create a project, synthesize it, fire up the simulation window and configure the in signals. Then, when clicking the button for launching Modelsim, it starts doing it's job, but ends up with

> ModelSim-Altera was not found. Please install ModelSim-Altera which is included with the Quartus II installer, or use the Quartus II Simulator instead by selecting "Simulation > Options > Quartus II Simulator"

This is simply not true. I can start Modelsim myself by running vsim. Here follows the full output. Any suggestions to resolve this will be +1 and no suggestions which would make sense will be punished by me.

```
Device family: Cyclone II
Running quartus eda_testbench
>> quartus_eda --gen_testbench --check_outputs=on --tool=modelsim_oem --format=verilog grindar -c grindar {--vector_source=/home/johan/Projects/Studies/vhdl/labs/lab1/and_grind.vwf} {--testbench_file=./simulation/qsim/grindar.vt}
PID = 20951
*******************************************************************
Running Quartus II 32-bit EDA Netlist Writer
  Version 13.0.1 Build 232 06/12/2013 Service Pack 1 SJ Web Edition
  Processing started: Sat Sep 12 20:31:33 2015
Command: quartus_eda --gen_testbench --check_outputs=on --tool=modelsim_oem --format=verilog grindar -c grindar --vector_source=/home/johan/Projects/Studies/vhdl/labs/lab1/and_grind.vwf --testbench_file=./simulation/qsim/grindar.vt
Selected device EP2C35F672C6 for design "grindar"
Generated Verilog Test Bench File ./simulation/qsim/grindar.vt for simulation
Quartus II 32-bit EDA Netlist Writer was successful. 0 errors, 0 warnings
  Peak virtual memory: 318 megabytes
  Processing ended: Sat Sep 12 20:31:34 2015
  Elapsed time: 00:00:01
  Total CPU time (on all processors): 00:00:01
Running quartus eda_func_netlist
>> quartus_eda --functional=on --simulation --tool=modelsim_oem --format=verilog grindar -c grindar
PID = 20953
*******************************************************************
Running Quartus II 32-bit EDA Netlist Writer
  Version 13.0.1 Build 232 06/12/2013 Service Pack 1 SJ Web Edition
  Processing started: Sat Sep 12 20:31:36 2015
Command: quartus_eda --functional=on --simulation=on --tool=modelsim_oem --format=verilog grindar -c grindar
Selected device EP2C35F672C6 for design "grindar"
Generated file grindar.vo in folder "/home/johan/Projects/Studies/vhdl/labs/lab1/simulation/modelsim/" for EDA simulation tool
Quartus II 32-bit EDA Netlist Writer was successful. 0 errors, 0 warnings
  Peak virtual memory: 318 megabytes
  Processing ended: Sat Sep 12 20:31:37 2015
  Elapsed time: 00:00:01
  Total CPU time (on all processors): 00:00:01
*******************************************************************
ModelSim-Altera was not found. Please install ModelSim-Altera which is included with the Quartus II installer, or use the Quartus II Simulator instead by selecting "Simulation > Options > Quartus II Simulator"
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check if the path to the ModelSim binary is correctly specified under 
Tools -> Options

[image]

I am in Windows, but hopefully the settings should be the same under Linux

Comment: I should have mentioned that I have ensured the correct path there. Unfortunately it does not help. Thank you anyway!

Comment: @Johan , Did you get around to solving the issue. It would help to know your experience.

Comment: No. I think there is a bug in Quartus 13 and Altera does not seem willing to address it. However, this is for University Program VWF which I don't need to use anymore. If running full RTL or grind simulation it works perfectly well.