# modelsim-altera was not found (linux)

Tags: linux, modelsim, intel-fpga

I've installed Quartus II 64-Bit on my PC under LinuxMint 17.3 OS. I don't have any problem with it. But I cann't run simulation with ModelSim-Altera. I get the message "ModelSim-Altera was not found...". [There is](https://www.badprog.com/electronics-quartus-ii-installing-modelsim-altera-starter-edition) the detailed instruction for installing ModelSim-Altera which I've performed. But it hasn't helped me. I've also tried to set "/" at end of path to ModelSim-Altera. Now I don't now what I have to do to make it able to run.

**Additional information:**

I also have the following error when running vsim:

** Fatal: Read failure in vlm process (0,0)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

I've tried to perform the instructions under [link](http://mattaw.blogspot.ru/2014/05/making-modelsim-altera-starter-edition.html) (problem number two), but I have the mentioned error yet.

After performing all instruction under the link above (problem number one and then problem number two) I got a well running vsim. But unfortunatly I cann't run ModelSim from Quartus II.

Comment: This or a similar issue was seen here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32559056/altera-quartus-falsly-says-modelsim-isnt-installed/32586843#32586843

Comment: Yes, it was. But unfortunately it wasn't solved. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old thread, but I came here looking for the answer and ended up everywhere else.
Adding this to .bashrc appears to have worked:

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/altera/13.0sp1/modelsim_ase/bin:~/altera/13.0sp1/quartus/bin
```

It may also be worth noting that I re-downloaded modelsim-altera, even though it said I already had it. I was not able to run modelsim_ase/linuxaloem/vsim (libXext.so.6 not found, although it too was installed) but it now appears to work. 64 bit Ubuntu 16.04.
Hopefully this helps someone else.

Edit: also `export QUARTUS_64BIT=1` in .bashrc